# Android: Multiclick at the same button

Tags: android

In my Application I have a simple image switcher and 2 buttons(Next and Previous) at the bottom of screen to switch images. Also I set animation to image switcher with duration 700. So when i click "Next" button firstly I disable next button, and than set to Clickable with delay with the same duration...because i need animation to be finished.

```
public void onNextButtonPressed(View view) {
    setPreviousAndNextButtonsClickable(false);
    setPeviousAndNextButtonsClickableWithDuration();
}

private void setPeviousAndNextButtonsClickableWithDuration() {
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setPreviousAndNextButtonsClickable(true);
        }
    }, 700);
}

 private void setPreviousAndNextButtonsClickable(boolean clicable) {
    nextButton.setClickable(clicable);
    previousButton.setClickable(clicable);
}
```

And now about my problem...When I click next button very faster, some time button can click two times with out delay...Looks like i can click faster than button.setCkickable() method work... What is the problem ? Can it be because of device ? I'm trying that on HTS with android 2.2 where I reproduce a bug...and also on android 2.3.4 where i cannot reproduce that...Is that because device is slow or something wrong in my code ? thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)
```

**delayMillis**     The delay (in milliseconds) until the `Runnable` will be executed.
Returns

I think your `button` gets enabled in 700 ms and that's a very small duration and that's why you are facing this issue.

Try increasing the delay and see.

Comment: I use Logger to see whats going on...And its shows that i click button faster than setClickable() method works...